# Hangfire RecurringJob "does not contain a method with signature"

Tags: c#, webapi, hangfire

I am using Hangfire configured in my WebAPI .NET Framework 4.7.2 application.
I am configuring it inside the Global.asax.cs
My dependency injection chain is configured using Autofac.

This is the way I am calling the recurring job

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<RunnerClass>(nameof(RunnerClass.MyMethod)+"_"+DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss"), r => r.MyMethod(), "* * * * *", queue: "specialqueue");
```

I am trying to make sure that this is delivered to a special queue that only my local application is listening to, to avoid other servers from picking this task up. Also, my task name is unique every time I fire up the WebAPI project to avoid picking up some old dll cache (not sure if this is possible)

My `MyMethod` implementation is as follows:

```
public class RunnerClass
{
     public RunnerClass(IDependenciesInjectedByAutofac dependency){
         //do something with dependencies
     }

     public string MyMethod(){
        // perform database calls to a database NOT the same where Hangfire schema lives
        // log some stuff to Cloud Provider
      var storeList = new List<Guid>();
       Parallel.ForEach(listOfGuids, g => { storeList.Add(MySubMethod(g)); }
       //some more DB stuff and logging
      return "finished";
     }

     public Guid MySubMethod(Guid guid){
      // do DB stuff
     }
}
```

This DOES NOT WORK. I get the following exception when running.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details. ---> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type `MyNamespace.RunnerClass` does not contain a method with signature `MyMethod()`
> at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
> at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity..ctor(String recurringJobId, IDictionary`2 recurringJob, ITimeZoneResolver timeZoneResolver, DateTime now)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now)

Now, this does not occur when I try to run normally using `BackgroundJob` instead of `RecurringJob`. This is very weird, since I am 100% no other instance is picking up my job.
Also worth saying that sometimes if I add a breakpoint inside the function invocation it works. Building the function from scratch allows me to add the recurring job, but suddenly it stops working without any apparent reason...

**EDIT**
It looks like cleaning the bin and obj directories works, until it just does not...

Is there something wrong in my invocation? I have tried to remove the Parallel.ForEach, but to no avail.

Comment: We've used HangFire in several of our web applications and always reverted to using a console application that is scheduled using the Windows Task Scheduler (presuming you are on Windows of course). That solved the majority of our problems always.

Comment: Clear your job queue storage. When you're using sql server, there'll be a `JobQueue` table (probably in the `hangfire` scheme). Do a `delete from hangfire.Jobqueue`.

Comment: Sadly in this case this table is empty for me. I guess this is being deleted when I manually delete the scheduling jobs from within the dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the job is being executed from the worker that is listening on a specific queue; only this worker needs the implementation. But creating (and enqueuing) a job from a recurring entry will be done by *any* Hangfire server. And this is what currently is failing. To avoid this problem, create a separate project that contains only a matching interface for your method and add this interface project to all your servers and within the recurring job creation call, also only use this interface.

Within your server listening on your special queue, register your implementation within the DI framework, so your local Hangfire worker knows what to pick to instantiate a class for the given interface.

By this approach every server can create/enqueue the job, but it will be processed only be the worker who is listening on the defined queue name.

Comment: What do you mean by "creating (and enqueuing) a job from a recurring entry will be done by any Hangfire server"? I am specifying the "specialqueue" during the job creation, and so only servers listening to this queue should pick up the job right?

Comment: Switching to a different non-used Hangfire database seem to have made things more stable. Does this mean that even if only one server is executing the job, other servers might be dequeuing and trying to deserialize the method?

Comment: Yes, other servers try to deserialize the method signature. Within the database the recurring job is stored as a serialized string of the method and its arguments. When the job should run, *any server* picks this recurring job, tries to deserialize the json into a `MethodInfo` and afterwards creates a new *real job* within the database state table by serializing this signature again and storing it. If the corresponding server doesn't have access to the assembly with this method, this creation fails and you won't get any job into the queue.

Comment: And this happens even if other servers are not listening to the queue the recurring job was sent to? Just want to confirm. If so, this does not look like a good design, since servers should only be deserializing jobs which were sent to their corresponding queues.

Comment: Yes, this is because it is nothing about listening on a specific queue. It is about creating a job within a specific queue. Recurring jobs are *not real jobs*. It's just about wanting a job at a specific point in time. And all servers watching for recurrent jobs and enqueue them into the specified queue when needed. Processing will be done by the specific listener, but creation from a recurring job, by any server.

Answer (score -1):

Na class add Startup services.AddHangfireServer()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).