# Unable to find the reason a Hangfire job fails

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am using Hangfire to schedule recurring jobs on my server. One of my jobs fails randomly, but I am unable to figure out why. The code it is actually running succeeds, according to my logs.

In my dashboard, all I see is an error without any description (unlike another job that failed, which got a description).

[Screenshot of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6MAM.png)

The job is scheduled as follows:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("[job name]", () => new [class name]().[function name](), Cron.Daily(20));
```

The default hangfire logs show the following:

```
2023-05-14 19:26:29.4164|TRACE|Hangfire.RecurringJobManager|Recurring job '[job name]' is being updated. RecurringJob: (CreatedAt:2023-05-09T16:09:12.2853777Z;Cron:0 20 * * *;Error:Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.;Job:{"Type":"[namespace], [project name], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","Method":"[method name]","ParameterTypes":"[]","Arguments":"[]"};NextExecution:;Queue:default;TimeZoneId:UTC;V:2), Changes: (NextExecution:2023-05-09T20:00:00.0000000Z;Error:), NextExecution: (5/9/2023 8:00:00 PM)
```

I'm thinking that if I could get my hands on the inner exceptions, I would be able to see where to go next.

I've tried to create an attribute for logging, as is suggested [here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/553). I can get it to log things like `OnPerforming`, but `OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)` doesn't seem to fire with any exceptions.

I have also tried to create a custom logger, as suggested [here](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html). As with the attribute, I can use it to log stuff, but I don't seem to get any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

As you've stated, without the inner exception it's a little difficult to know exactly what's wrong.

"Could not load the job." means that the method was not found and so the job couldn't be processed, which would mean the dll isn't available to the worker process. Since the job runs fine sometimes, we know that at least one worker process can enqueue and run the job.

Could be caused by:

1. multiple applications using the same Hangfire DB.
2. multiple worker processes and one is missing the dll.

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72228098/1038027) any worker process can attempt to enqueue the recurrent job when the time comes.

Comment: I have tried to look over the hang fire tables and haven't been able to find it.
What I have noticed looking at my server logs, is that the job completes just fine. The job seems to work well 1 to 3 times (happens once daily). Then suddenly there's an error in rescheduling the job. 

I've never seen the job actually fail when running, and it doesn't take long at all. So the error seems to be more on the hang fire side of things than the routine it executes.

Comment: @user2946756 Are you using one of the logging frameworks listed on the "Configuring Logging" page you link to? You mentioned trying to create your own so maybe not. I'm just surprised that the exception isn't being output into the normal logs. I'm looking at putting Hangfire into an application so will have a look and get back to you.

Comment: I haven log and I do get logs from Hangfire, the unfortunate thing is that it just tells me to view the inner exception for details without actually showing it.
So what I tried to do is to detect various state transitions, etc.

Comment: @user2946756 Can you see, in the job lists, that a job is being enqueued and attempting to run? Does it retry the job, and if so do you get different exceptions each time? Do you have multiple workers and queues?

Comment: @user2946756 If the job isn't being queued this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72228098/1038027) might be relevant. In summary, a worker which doesn't know about your method, may pick up the recurring job to enqueue it, but fail when it can't find the method.